# How to make My MVC4 application to mobile /tab compatibility?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Its my basic question, but I think it is worth it. I have MVC4 application which is working absolutely on my PC/laptop browser. What next to do work in mobiles/tab also? The application has all latest Jquery, bootstrap, HTML5 and Razor engine code.

Will same application open mobile browser in smaller size? How to make to work?

Answer (score 2):

There are three alternatives.

1. You can create a native mobile application (IOS, Android and so on) for your web application. Assuming you want to stick with your current app, this choice is useless for you.
2. There are frameworks such as [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) that enables you to write views for your web application that are used in when your application is accessed via mobile devices such as tablets and phones.
3. Last option is using [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) techniques. This is especially good when most of the content on the pages are static. If you have used bootstrap, as far as I know, it is a front-end framework that is responsive. In that case, you do not need to do anything.

You can test your application behavior using Chrome developer tools (F12). Just go to settings in developer tools and override the device metrics to resolution you want to test. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-803T?ocid=aff-n-in-loc--hr

You have all u want here in above link...

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.